# Split a Total into subtotal under different columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns `Grp` and `CHD`

```
Grp     CHD
20-29      0
20-29       1
20-29       0
30-34       1
30-34       0
```

I want to generate a new dataframe from this as below

```
grp    n      ChDP CHDA  Mean
20-29 10      1      2   0.1
30-35 15      2     13   0.133
```

where

grp = grp
n = grp count
CHDP = total(CHD = 1) in the group
CHDA = total(CHD = 0) in the group
Mean = CHDP/n

How can I create this dataframe in R?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` to create a `result` dataframe and then use `tapply` to create the other columns.
First, the dataset.

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
Grp     CHD
20-29      0
20-29       1
20-29       0
30-34       1
30-34       0
", header = TRUE)
```

Now the code.

```
result <- aggregate(CHD ~ Grp, dat, length)
result$CHDP <- tapply(dat$CHD, dat$Grp, FUN = function(x) sum(x == 1))
result$CHDA <- tapply(dat$CHD, dat$Grp, FUN = function(x) sum(x == 0))
result$Mean <- tapply(dat$CHD, dat$Grp, FUN = function(x) mean(x == 1))
result
#    Grp CHD CHDP CHDA      Mean
#1 20-29   3    1    2 0.3333333
#2 30-34   2    1    1 0.5000000
```